# ACL settings for civicrm in Joomla cannot be reset anymore

Tags: joomla, acl

Using CiviCRM 4.6.15 (and later 4.6.16) integrated in Joomla 3.5.1 I just found out that it is no longer possible to change ACL settings for CiviCRM. It is possible to change a setting, this change is ajaxified and will be shown immediately, however after saving the change it is rolled back to the setting before the change.

I see this in a site that I upgraded from an earlier Civi version, and also in an install of CiviCRM 4.7.6 in a Joomla 3.5.1 site.
The readme text with the ACL settings advised to set the value of 'max_input_vars' (defult 1000) higher. I reset this to 2000 and later to 8000.
This does not solve the issue with CiviCRM 4.7.6 (now 4.7.7) in Joomla 3.5.1 however.

This seems to be a longstanding bug, see: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15841.

Comment: My site is running Joomla 3.5.1 with CiviCRM 4.7.5 and I'm experiencing the same issue even after changing and verifying that max_input_vars is set to 4500.

Comment: Same problem with Joomla 3.5.1 and CiviCRM 4.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating Joomla 3.5.1 to the latest version Joomla 3.6.0 this problem seems to have disappeared completely.
I checked a civi 4.6.19 and a civi 4.7.9 install and both behave well again. You can now change the AVL settings again.
I did hear that the acl-part of Joomla needed and got some TLC so I presume this was the culprit in the previous Joomla version.

I did not need to to set the value of 'max_input_vars' (default 1000) higher for this to work.